# Python - Plot axes descale in density plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, density-plot

I have this initial plot.

[image]

Here is the code for this,

```
x = subhalos['SubhaloVelDisp']
y = (subhalos['SubhaloBHMass'] * 1e10 / 0.704) # in units of M_sol h^-1

logx = np.log(x)
logy = np.log(y)

plt.plot(logx, logy, '.')

plt.ylabel('$\log(M_{BH}$ / M$_{\odot}$)' )
plt.xlabel(' $\log(\sigma_{1D}$ / km s$^{-1}$)')
plt.title('$M_{BH}-\sigma$ relation')
```

Now, when plotting a density representation, my results are successful, giving me this, BUT my units on my axes have completely changed, yet it stills preserves the shape from the initial plot.

[image]

```
x = subhalos['SubhaloVelDisp']
y = subhalos['SubhaloBHMass'] * 1e10 / 0.704 # in units of M_sol h^-1


X = np.log10(x)
Y = np.log10(y)

x1 = X[np.isfinite(X)]
y1 = Y[np.isfinite(Y)]

x1.resize(y1.shape)

xy = np.vstack([x1,y1])
z = stats.gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)

idx = z.argsort()
x,y,z = x1[idx],y1[idx],z[idx]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(X,Y,c=z, s=25, edgecolor='')
plt.ylabel('$\log(M_{BH}$ / M$_{\odot}$)' )
plt.xlabel(' $\log(\sigma_{1D}$ / km s$^{-1}$)')
plt.title('$M_{BH}-\sigma$ relation')
```

The key things are that when passing the two arrays `x` and `y` in log form, I will get NaN values in the array. I then run both of them through the `np.isfinite` module and then i resize both of the arrays so that they are both the same shape.

What is going on here to have my values change on my axes?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand the entire sequence but it looks like the difference in the axes is that you used

```
logx = np.log(x)
logy = np.log(y)
```

in the first example, and

```
X = np.log10(x)
Y = np.log10(y)
```

in the second.